# Working generically with variable-sized data known at the compile time.

Tags: c

Consider the requirement to write a simple API for dealing with arbitrary-degree polynomials.
A simple one would be something like the following:

```
#define POLYNOM_MAX_ORDER   10

typedef struct polynom_struct
{
    int order;
    float coeffs[POLYNOM_MAX_ORDER];
} polynom_t;

// Polynomial initialization 
// p - a pointer to polynomial instance
// order - the degree of the polynomial
// coeffs - array of the polynomial coefficients of length order+1
void polynom_init(polynom_t* p, int order, float coeffs[])
{
    int i;
    p -> order = order;
    for(i=0; i <= p->order; i++)
    {
        p->coeffs[i] = coeffs[i];
    }
}

// Polynomial value calculation at point "x"
float polynom_calc_point(polynom_t* p, float x)
{
    int i;
    float result =  p->coeffs[0];

    for(i=1; i <= p->order; i++)
    {
        result += x * p->coeffs[i];
        x *= x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now consider similar API is required for a resources-constrained embedded system, i.e. two requirements are added: no extra *unused* memory memory should be allocated and *no dynamic memory allocation* allowed (on heap, may consider some stack-based allocation). Clearly the code above is violating the first requirement, as the `coeffs` field is allocating the maximum regardless of will it be used or not. The second requirement is preventing us from allocating the required memory dynamically.

As well it is clear that there is no way of solving this problem if the polynomial orders are not known at the compile time. But what if they are? What if we *know* we are going to hardcode `N` polynomials with orders `{O_1, O_2, .., O_N}`, how can we represent the generic API similar (or perhaps different?) to above for working with them while within the stated requirements?

Comment: Minor point: Consider not accessing `p->coeffs[0]` unless `p->order > 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that answers your question, but you might try with *flexible array member* (since C99), where the last member (here `coeffs`) can be of various size for each object.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct polynom_struct
{
    int order;
    float coeffs[];
} polynom_t;

polynom_t a = { 1, { 1.0f } };
polynom_t b = { 2, { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f } };

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", a.coeffs[0]);
    printf("%f\n", b.coeffs[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

The ability for static initilization of flexible array member is a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html):

> GCC allows static initialization of flexible array members. This is
>   equivalent to defining a new structure containing the original
>   structure followed by an array of sufficient size to contain the data.

Comment: OK, now that's interesting... What would be `sizeof(polynom_t)` ? Anyway, really interesting, thank you. It looks like the right direction. Extra beer for a C89 solution :)

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: The `sizeof(polynom_t)` does not include last member. It practically the same as it would be zero length array (another GCC extension).

Comment: Is there a way of statically allocating them without initializer?

Comment: I am afraid there isn't much possibility. The compiler must know size of flexible array member when object is defined.

Comment: Yeah, I see no magic here unfortunately. I addition no way to nest such a members in other structures.

Answer (score 1):

[@Grzegorz Szpetkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32127682/2410359) is a good answer.  Thought I'd try my hand at something that may meet the "statically allocating" desire.

The main idea is to assume a small number of different array sizes and create a typedef'd structure for each.  `array2_T` is for 2 elements, `array3_T` is for 3 elements, etc.

The struct is initialized with `array_init(void *anon, size_t anon_size)` which cheats with a `void *` argument.  Later code simply uses the returned pointers.

```
// array.h
typedef struct {
  size_t size;
  int array[];
} array_T;

array_T *array_init(void *anon, size_t anon_size);
void array_foo(array_T *a);
void array_foo_this(array_T *a);
void array_foo_that(array_T *a);
// ... various array_ functions

// array.c
array_T *array_init(void *anon, size_t anon_size) {
  array_T *a = (array_T *) anon;
  a->size = (anon_size - sizeof a->size) / sizeof *a->array;
  memset(a->array, 0, a->size * sizeof *a->array);
  return a;
}

// Lots of various functions using `array_some_name(array_T *a, ...`
void array_foo(array_T *a) {
  // do _something_
  if (a->size > 0) a->size--;
}

// foo.c
typedef struct {
  size_t size;
  int array[2];
} array2_T;

typedef struct {
  size_t size;
  int array[3];
} array3_T;

void bar(void) {
  array2_T a2;
  array3_T a3;
  array_T *g2 = array_init(&a2, sizeof a2);
  array_T *g3 = array_init(&a3, sizeof a3);

  // Lots of code using g2,g3
  array_foo(g2);
  array_foo(g3);
}
```

Comment: I was looking into something like this. Would it work if in `array_T` we declare `array` as `int*` or zero-sized array, as it will make it complete type?

Comment: @Eugene `int array[0];` is not that portable.  `int *array` is not an array, but a pointer that needs to point to some allocated space.  The pointer idea _is_ another approach.  Something like `typedef struct {
  size_t size;
  int array[];
} arrayp_T;

  int ar2[2];
  arrayp_T a = { sizeof ar2/sizeof *ar2, ar2 }; `  I think I like this even better.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the polynomials and their order, why not just statically allocate one array with the total size of all coefficients and store in the struct polynom_struct just a pointer to the start of the coefficients of that polynomial. You only need one more static variable to remember where the free coefficients start in the array.

```
typedef struct polynom_struct
{
    int order;
    float *coeffs;
} polynom_t;

void polynom_init(polynom_t* p, int order, float coeffs[])
{
  static float all_coeffs[TOTAL_COEFFS];
  static int pos = 0;

  p->coeffs = &all_coeffs[pos];
  pos = pos + order;

  for(...)
}
```

Comment: This is kind of poor-man-`malloc` approach I was considering, but it is kinda... ugly :)

Comment: Well, C89 is not known for its beauty, but for its ability to get things done ;)